# Merge Sort JavaScript Implementation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mergesort

I'm doing a course on Khan Academy on Algorithms.
I usually try to figure out the examples by myself but this time I am really not getting it. The exercise is at: [Khan Academy Merge Sort Exercise](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/merge-sort/p/challenge-implement-merge-sort).
So I'm asking a kind person to please resolve this exercise for me, because I'm stuck and it is the first time that I can't implement something. I'm sure that I will understand the algorithm (I think I do, but it gives me errors on implementing, so apparently I'm not understanding) after seem the resolution.
Here is the code that I have done so far:

```
// Takes in an array that has two sorted subarrays,
//  from [p..q] and [q+1..r], and merges the array
var merge = function(array, p, q, r) {
    // This code has been purposefully obfuscated,
    //  as you'll write it yourself in next challenge.
    var a=[],b=[],c=p,d,e;for(d=0;c<=q;d++,c++){a[d]=array[c];}for(e=0;c<=r;e++,c++){b[e]=array[c];}c=p;for(e=d=0;d<a.length&&e<b.length;){if(a[d]<b[e]){array[c]=a[d];d++;} else {array[c]=b[e]; e++;}c++; }for(;d<a.length;){array[c]=a[d];d++;c++;}for(;e<b.length;){array[c]=b[e];e++;c++;}
};


// Takes in an array and recursively merge sorts it
var mergeSort = function(array, p, r) {
    if(r > 1) {
        var q = Math.floor((p + r) / 2);
        mergeSort(array,p,q);
        mergeSort(array,q+1,r);
        merge(array, p, q, r);
    }

};

var array = [14, 7, 3, 12, 9, 11, 6, 2];
console.log(''+array);
mergeSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
console.log("Array after sorting: " + array);
```

```js
// Takes in an array that has two sorted subarrays,
    //  from [p..q] and [q+1..r], and merges the array
    var merge = function(array, p, q, r) {
        // This code has been purposefully obfuscated,
        //  as you'll write it yourself in next challenge.
        var a=[],b=[],c=p,d,e;for(d=0;c<=q;d++,c++){a[d]=array[c];}for(e=0;c<=r;e++,c++){b[e]=array[c];}c=p;for(e=d=0;d<a.length&&e<b.length;){if(a[d]<b[e]){array[c]=a[d];d++;} else {array[c]=b[e]; e++;}c++; }for(;d<a.length;){array[c]=a[d];d++;c++;}for(;e<b.length;){array[c]=b[e];e++;c++;}
    };
    
    
    // Takes in an array and recursively merge sorts it
    var mergeSort = function(array, p, r) {
        if(r > 1) {
            var q = Math.floor((p + r) / 2);
            mergeSort(array,p,q);
            mergeSort(array,q+1,r);
            merge(array, p, q, r);
        }
        
    };
    
    var array = [14, 7, 3, 12, 9, 11, 6, 2];
    console.log(''+array);
    mergeSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
    console.log("Array after sorting: " + array);
```

Comment: How about showing your attempt instead of requiring a full solution? Finding the gotchas from your own code would be more useful thinking about your learning, than that you would copy-paste a ready-to-go solution.

Comment: @Teemu my attempt is the code that I have gave you

Comment: It is? Please use meaningful variable names then, that's the first step to success.

Comment: What is the error here? What went wrong? Are there errors shown in console? Can you isolate the issue? Have you tried logging each step? Please don't expect people to find the error, fix it for you and then explain the same.

Comment: Check your base case. When does the recursion need to end? What values would `p` and `r` have?

Comment: I believe that merge sort should divide until it get an array with 1 or 2 elements. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with the `if` condition

what the if condition achieves is to check that the `r` that is end of array is greater that `p` start of the array.

I'm not sure what `r > 1` is trying to do. hence it doesn't get satisfied and executes recursively untill it runs out of stack space

```js
// Takes in an array that has two sorted subarrays,
//  from [p..q] and [q+1..r], and merges the array
var merge = function(array, p, q, r) {
  // This code has been purposefully obfuscated,
  //  as you'll write it yourself in next challenge.
  var a = [],
    b = [],
    c = p,
    d, e;
  for (d = 0; c <= q; d++, c++) {
    a[d] = array[c];
  }
  for (e = 0; c <= r; e++, c++) {
    b[e] = array[c];
  }
  c = p;
  for (e = d = 0; d < a.length && e < b.length;) {
    if (a[d] < b[e]) {
      array[c] = a[d];
      d++;
    } else {
      array[c] = b[e];
      e++;
    }
    c++;
  }
  for (; d < a.length;) {
    array[c] = a[d];
    d++;
    c++;
  }
  for (; e < b.length;) {
    array[c] = b[e];
    e++;
    c++;
  }
};


// Takes in an array and recursively merge sorts it
var mergeSort = function(array, p, r) {
  if (r > p) {
    var q = Math.floor((p + r) / 2);
    mergeSort(array, p, q);
    mergeSort(array, q + 1, r);
    merge(array, p, q, r);
  }

};

var array = [14, 7, 3, 12, 9, 11, 6, 2];
console.log('' + array);
mergeSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
console.log("Array after sorting: " + array);
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much. I have tried `r > 1` and `r - p > 0` but none of them was being accepted. Thank you again for sticking with me @thebenman although some people don't understand that I have tried my best and recurring for a solution on stackoverflow was a desperate measure. Blessings for your life

Comment: Thank you. `r - p > 0` is identical to `r > p` not sure why that would fail

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't remember quite well, I tried a lot of options, but I know that I treid `r - p > 1` or maybe it was `p - r > 1`... `> 0` I'm not sure that I tried. Or maybe Khan Academy only accepts `r > p`. Don't know and now I don't really care about it. Thanks @thebenman ;)